# Update to Xamarin touch 8.2 and use mvvmcross

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

We are using xamarin and mvvmcross with great plesure normmally.

However I updated our project to the newest Xamarin.Ios 8.2, changed the reference from monotouch to Xamarin.Ios updated all our nuget packages (only mvvmcross packages) and then sh.. hit the fan.

1000 errors :P I got ridth of them all, however everytime I am using a component from mvvmcross it want me to reference 'module monotouch should be referenced.

Any suggestion for what I am needing to get my project to build again.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin's advice on the unified API is http://blog.xamarin.com/is-the-ios-unified-api-for-me/

> Unfortunately, existing Xamarin.iOS components need to be re-built against the Unified API, so while we (and the community) are working to update the component code, you will not be able to include these in your app. A workaround for open-source projects is to download and compile the code yourself as part of your Unified API project.

@lothrop is doing a superb job leading the Unified API development for MvvmCross

You can see the progress, build it and contribute to it on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/813 (and see a discussion on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/801)

Currently I believe the progress is pretty good - it's working - but we have some VisualStudio Xamarin blockers which are preventing this being pushed to release.

---

Getting more dev effort on this - more input to https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/813 and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/801 - would certainly be appreciated. e.g. the community can help by building and using @lothrop's code - does it work for them?

Comment: Hi Start, Thank you for your answer. Maybe I should have done a bit more reading before charging at update. For now I will probably revert our project back. But I will take a look at @lothrop progress and implement it / try it out, just need to do it parallel to my normal work - we could all use a bit of 64bitshizzle :)